# IE11 document mode 7 issue on a website on one server but not so on another server

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2012-r2, ie-compatibility-mode

On `IE 11`, when we browse through our website that is deployed on `Windows Server 2012` (**not** R2), the website correctly displays its home page (as shown in figure 1 below). But if the exact same website is deployed on another server that is `windows Sever 2012` **R2**, and browse through it on IE11, it displays completely messed up as shown in figure 2 below. If we use IE Developer tool (`F12`) on second website, we get the following error on the console tab of the tool, but there is no such error when we do F12 on the website from the first server. This leads us to believe that this is something to do with the servers where the website is installed. We tried a suggested solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27272454/1232087) post but no success. **Question**: What are the possible causes and how can we remedy them? Website is using `Bootstrap 1.3`.

> The attached page targets document mode 7. some console apis and features may not be available.

**From IE11 when the webswite is on Windows 2012 server**:

[image]

**From IE11 when the exact same webswite is on Windows 2012 R2 server**:

[image]

Comment: Examine your web.config file and asp.net code behind..... replace all occurrences of localhost or 127.0.0.1 with the appropriate token... eg. ~/path/file.aspx... viz: somewhere in your code (most likely in web.config) you have coded localhost. You should not use server versions of windows for testing as they run in an enhanced protected mode. localhost is the webroot on servers... all hosts reside under it.Use the Website>Publish menu in VS when deploying. Make sure you do not over-write the production version of web.config.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` in `<head></head>`.

I suppose the problem is the same as here [IE11 Document mode defaults to IE7. How to reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset).